# Excluding IE 6/7 traffic

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I would like to ask if there is any easy way of displaying different page for IE6/7 users who enter a website.

Like a redirect from example.com to example.com/ie7

Unfortunately IE7 doesn't like the website I made so I want to display miniversion of the original website, I have put too much effort into the original to downgrade it now.

Will this line always work? On every version/build of IE7? Or is it more complicated?

I want to be sure that **100%** of IE7 traffic gets redirected.

```
 <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.example.com/ie7"><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want `<!--[if lt IE 8]>`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a different CSS on the same page to get a simpler result

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link href="/IE7style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
```

Just overwrite all the styling needed to make IE7 happy

Answer (score 2):

to serve content to IE7 , you need to set the version in conditionnal comments.

```
<!--[if IE 7 ]><p>I'm IE 7</p><![endif]-->
```

IE7 and lower :

```
 <!--[if lte IE 7 ]><p>I'm IE 7 at the most.</p><![endif]-->
```

Where `lte` means Lighter Than or Equal

Answer (score 0):

The better way is

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.example.com/ie7";
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be done server side. You can use something like [ua-parser](https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser) to detect ie <=7, and redirect to a new site accordingly.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? You can do it client side, but if you are serving a completely different page, then there is no reason for you to be serving the entire page to a client who is never going to be using that code.